# Using BeautifulSoup, Requests and Selenium. Only get the new links in an infinitely scrolling web page

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests, infinite-scroll

Is it possible using BeautifulSoup, requests and selenium to only get the new links in an infinitely scrolling web page?

For example say I get all the image links and do what I need with them, then I scroll down and more load how can I just get the new ones that load?

I think I could compare the links to get the new one but that would be very inefficient I presume.

Comment: I think you need to have some kind of a `sentinel` variable to indicate how many items, e.g, images you have seen up to this round, let's say `x` and then start from the item `x+1`

Comment: @YannisP Thank you! I can't believe I didn't think of that. Its very simple but should work. Thanks!